# How to convert to 8 digits in etherum

Tags: solidity, metamask, javascript

I have a token that has 8 digits, so the output is 4762575931 instead of 47.62575..

How can i change this so this works on UI and for metamask input?

I know there is the function to wei but this is for 18 decimals.

What do i do for 8 decimals?
I dont see a conversion for 8 decimals

Comment: How about dividing by 100000000?

Comment: BTW, `toWei` does the general opposite of what you're asking, which makes your entire question rather unclear.

Comment: In order to convert user input to contract input, you need to multiply by `10 ** 8` and truncate (`Math.floor`). In order to convert from contract output to user output, you need to divide by `10 ** 8`.

Comment: I use this document.getElementById('agiAvailable').innerHTML = agiAccountBalance/100000000;  how does that look with math floor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimals property of a token is basically a hint to UI for how to render token amounts.  So, your problem is purely UI problem.  Basically, what you need to do, is to divide token amounts by `10^decimals` before showing these amounts to the user, and multiply token amounts, provided by the user, by the same coefficient, before sending them to the blockchain.  You just need to use right library for this arithmetic, namely a library, that:

1. is able to handle number as large as 2^256-1, and
2. Is able to handle decimal fractions without loss of precision.

Suitable libraries exist for all major languages, for Javascript you may use this one: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/